# useradd with no options

Tags: linux, users, administration, useradd

When I create a user with `useradd` (no option) I can later add his passwd by using `passwd new_user`.

How can I create his correct home directory (with Desktop and Templates inside) and all other parameters the user needs?

I mean how can I obtain the equivalent of `adduser`?

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usermod` to modify an existing account. However this will not populate the user's HOME directory as `useradd --create-home` does.

Instead, you have to do it yourself.

```
# Consider a user 'fred'
user=fred
skel=$(. /etc/defaults/useradd 2>/dev/null; echo "$SKEL")
home=$(getent passwd "$user" | cut -d: -f6)
gid=$(getent passwd "$user" | cut -d: -f4)
mkdir -p -m755 "$home"
cp -a "${skel:-/etc/skel}/." "$user"
chown -R "$user":"$gid" "$home"
```

Missing XDG directories will be created as the user first logs in.

Comment: I get errors on --> cp -a "${skel-/etc/skel}/." "$user" ...

Comment: @pietroletti found it. Mobile phone typo. Sigh.

Comment: what's the utility of the simple command: useradd new-user if I can't populate the home directory later?

Comment: @pietroletti why wouldn't you want to populate the home directory when you created the user with `useradd`?

Comment: that's just curiosity: if a command exist it should be for something -> if I do useradd new_user the system add a new user -> what's for if it's not directly possible to add a home to that user?  --> what else I can do with a user who has not a home directory?

Comment: @pietroletti there's nothing stopping you either extending `usermod` or writing your own as a script. I've often extended system tools with extra features - either using the same command but adding new features (I have `/usr/local/bin` and `$HOME/bin` near the front of my `$PATH` so I can do exactly this) or by creating my own variant. In this case you could create `userhome` that create a user's home directory using pretty much the code I've supplied in this Answer.

Comment: @pietroletti I've just re-read your comment. `user-add` can create a user's directory. But you have to tell it to do so with `--create-home`.